# How can I adjust my positive lookahead RegEx statement?

Tags: regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have a really simple question about my positive lookahead, but I don't get it.

My String looks like this:

> caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: 3285673465734

And I am using this RegEx:

```
caused by: (.+(?=:)): (.+)[\s]+
```

I want to have this groups:

1. System.StringException
2. Invalid id: 3285673465734

but the positive lookahead separates the string at the second ':' and I get this groups:

1. System.StringException: Invalid id:
2. 3285673465734

How can I adjust my RegEx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead isn't even needed here, you can simplify your regex to:

```
caused by: +([^:]+): +(.+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eV7tO0/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one (no lookahead needed)

```
caused by: ([^:\n]+): (.*\S)
```